# Specifying constraints for fmin_cobyla in scipy

Tags: python, function, lambda, scipy, specifications

I use Python 2.5.

I am passing bounds to the cobyla optimisation:

```
import numpy 
from numpy import asarray

Initial = numpy.asarray [2, 4, 5, 3]       # Initial values to start with

#bounding limits (lower,upper) - for visualizing

#bounds = [(1, 5000), (1, 6000), (2, 100000), (1, 50000)] 

# actual passed bounds

b1 = lambda  x: 5000 - x[0]      # lambda x: bounds[0][1] - Initial[0]

b2 = lambda  x: x[0] - 2.0       # lambda x: Initial[0] - bounds[0][0]

b3 = lambda  x: 6000 - x[1]      # same as above

b4 = lambda  x: x[1] - 4.0

b5 = lambda  x: 100000 - x[2]

b6 = lambda  x: x[2] - 5.0

b7 = lambda  x: 50000 - x[3]

b8 = lambda  x: x[3] - 3.0

b9 = lambda  x: x[2] >  x[3]  # very important condition for my problem!


opt= optimize.fmin_cobyla(func,Initial,cons=[b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10],maxfun=1500000)
```

Based on the initial values `Initial` and as per/within the bounds `b1` to `b10` the values  are passed to `opt()`. But the values are deviating, especially with `b9`. This is a very important bounding condition for my problem!

"The value of `x[2]` passed to my function `opt()` at every iteration must be always greater than `x[3]`" -- How is it possible to achieve this?

Is there anything wrong in my bounds (`b1` to `b9`) definition ?

Or is there a better way of defining of my bounds?

Please help me.

Comment: I would revise the title to indicate this is a question about how to specify constraints for scipy's fmin_cobyla function, not about how lambdas are specified in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fmin_cobyla()` is not an interior point method. That is, it will pass points that are outside of the bounds ("infeasible points") to the function during the course of the optmization run.

On thing that you will need to fix is that `b9` and `b10` are not in the form that `fmin_cobyla()` expects. The bound functions need to return a positive number if they are within the bound, 0.0 if they are exactly on the bound, and a negative number if they are out of bounds. Ideally, these functions should be smooth. `fmin_cobyla()` will try to take numerical derivatives of these functions in order to let it know how to get back to the feasible region.

```
b9 = lambda x: x[2] - x[3]
```

I'm not sure how to implement `b10` in a way that `fmin_cobyla()` will be able to use, though.

Comment: `max(x) - min(x)` might work -- it is reasonably smooth, > 0 the more "within bounds" x is, == 0 when "exactly on the bound" (I see no way to be "outside" a 1-D bound with a 4-D point;-).

Comment: x[2]-x[3] > 0 and x[2] > x[3] are equivalent conditions

Comment: Thank you, its getting better with lambda x: x[2] - x[3], but i am getting the stage where the value of x[2] & x[3] are same, but if i want to pass b9 = lambda x: x[2] > x[3] "the value of x[2] must be always greater than x[3] value". For that what change should i make? 
please see the edited code.

Answer (score 2):

for b10, a possible option could be:

```
b10 = lambda x: min(abs(i-j)-d for i,j in itertools.combinations(x,2))
```

where *d* is a delta greater than the minimum difference you want between your variables (e.g 0.001)

Comment: Excellent idea ! unfortunately i use only python 2.5, the main problem is opt()should firmly stick to b9 = lambda  x: x[2] >  x[3] , x[2] must be always greater than x[3] this condition very important for my   problem. How to code b9 condition?